# Android:Emulator is not working properly it is giving rendering error

Tags: android, android-emulator

i created new emulator with all the data needed while creating as shown in the image below. i am not able to compile inside the emulator if anyone know how to make it correct pls let me know and thanks for your time

[image]

and in the image below the loaded emulator is shown.
which is not loading properly and some colors are displaying

[image]

Comment: if i leave the emulator then it will not load till hours

Comment: Try genymotion emulator

Comment: is it inbuilt in eclipse @user974801 or we have to download externally

Comment: They have a plugin for eclipse but you need to install some components by yourself http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: @user974801 ya i will check and let u know

Comment: do u have documentation to setup genymotion to my eclipse @user974801

Comment: There is tutorial on genymotion page - you need to create user

Comment: ya got it @user974801

Answer (score 1):

Hi kindly do the below changes.Target any more than api level 14.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer ? Why API Level > 14 will solve the problem?

Comment: API Level > 14 will not be the issue. for example  i used this. you can set any level >8

Comment: wait i will check and let u know @Raptor

Comment: but after loading it will tell as updating @Sivakumar